# Rails 3.2 / Haml / Two forms on one page, the second one is not rendered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, haml

I'd like to have two forms rendered in one view, however, only the first form tag is rendered. The second one is ignored.

Code snippet:

```
#form_1
  = form_tag(controller: "auto_discover", action: "foo")
#form_2
  = form_tag(controller: "auto_discover", action: "bar")
```

HTML generated (snipped):

```
<div id="form_1">
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/services/autodiscover/auto_discover/foo" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" value="✓" type="hidden"><input name="authenticity_token" value="hCb2xmXWSiwCpyVcqQJe6rHZjEvpc1pcfA1Ru7kytRo=" type="hidden">
...
</form></div>
<div id="form_2">
  ...no form...</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried only passing the url in the form_tag? e.g. `= form_tag('/path_to_action')`

Comment: I tried now but it didn't work

Comment: please post more relevant code